# При запросе файла, выдавать другой url, через .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте у меня есть сайт написан на PHP 5.6 у меня есть страница для просмотра товара ссылка примерно выглядит так view.php?view_id=5
Я бы хотел заменить её через .htaccess на допустим /book/new-book-5/

Comment: то что вы хотите сделать ЧПУ называется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите `RewriteEngine` и напишите соответствующее `RewriteRule` правило замены. Первым параметром является строка или шаблон входящей ссылки, вторым - сопоставление. далее могут следовать, или не следовать, флаги.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^book/new-book-([\d]+)/?$    view.php?view_id=$1   [NC,L]
```

флаг `NC` определяет регистронезависимое сравнение, флаг `L` завершает текущий цикл обработки.
Так что вашей ссылка должна работать в вараинтах:

```
/book/new-book-5
/book/new-book-5/
/Book/new-Book-5
```